# Using glmer function but no p value or f stat

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I am trying to run a generalized linear mixed effect model in R using the glmer function from lme4 package.

I have included my data and code. My response variable (CVknown) is negatively skewed towards the 0 (see image).

So I assumed I should use the poison distribution (family = poison). But when I look at the model It does not give me p values (or f stat) like it should? Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using a different family or a different function in R?

[image]

```
model1 <- glmer(CVknown ~ Method * Known_Age + (1|ID), data=raw_data, family = poisson)
model1
```

```
data <- structure(list(Method = c("Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", "Traditioal", 
                                  "Traditioal", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", 
                                  "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", 
                                  "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", 
                                  "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", 
                                  "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", 
                                  "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", 
                                  "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", 
                                  "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel", "Novel"), ID = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                          12L, 23L, 34L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                                                                                          8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
                                                                                                          22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 
                                                                                                          37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
                                                                                                          1L, 12L, 23L, 34L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                                          7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
                                                                                                          21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 
                                                                                                          36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
                                                                                                          50L), .Label = c("Fish1", "Fish10", "Fish11", "Fish12", "Fish13", 
                                                                                                                           "Fish14", "Fish15", "Fish16", "Fish17", "Fish18", "Fish19", "Fish2", 
                                                                                                                           "Fish20", "Fish21", "Fish22", "Fish23", "Fish24", "Fish25", "Fish26", 
                                                                                                                           "Fish27", "Fish28", "Fish29", "Fish3", "Fish30", "Fish31", "Fish32", 
                                                                                                                           "Fish33", "Fish34", "Fish35", "Fish36", "Fish37", "Fish38", "Fish39", 
                                                                                                                           "Fish4", "Fish40", "Fish41", "Fish42", "Fish43", "Fish44", "Fish45", 
                                                                                                                           "Fish46", "Fish47", "Fish48", "Fish49", "Fish5", "Fish50", "Fish51", 
                                                                                                                           "Fish52", "Fish53", "Fish54", "Fish6", "Fish7", "Fish8", "Fish9"
                                                                                                          ), class = "factor"), Known_Age = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                                                                                                                              5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                                                                                                                                              8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
                                                                                                                                              7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                                                                                                                              5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 
                                                                                                                                              7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), CVknown = c(17.30680933, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        15.43877277, 0, 2.142747822, 10.87856586, 2.142747822, 6.071118828, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        2.142747822, 15.43877277, 10.47565602, 12.14223766, 8.570991287, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        18.41481141, 4.285495644, 13.92786084, 7.582030754, 9.724778576, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        13.28163531, 9.999489835, 23.17307205, 11.71688921, 1.571348403, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        9.243225898, 4.159451654, 2.618914004, 14.72212266, 0, 2.957832287, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 4.938523551, 4.714045208, 1.386483885, 0, 6.509871954, 4.159451654, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        5.915664575, 4.714045208, 7.463904913, 11.23051947, 3.142696805, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        2.946278255, 16.72075864, 0, 0, 8.677078312, 13.19470497, 8.380524814, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 2.946278255, 9.715163682, 4.517626658, 8.677078312, 10.21376462, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        9.035253315, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.618914004, 10.47565602, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 0, 10.47565602, 0, 10.47565602, 0, 2.618914004, 5.237828009, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 7.252377243, 0, 0, 7.252377243, 9.065471554, 3.626188621, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        3.142696805, 0, 0, 7.554559628, 0, 10.87856586, 1.813094311, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.813094311, 10.87856586, 0, 7.010631335, 0, 1.813094311, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        7.911684265, 0, 0, 1.813094311, 1.813094311, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.768936443, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -108L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example code and data you provided, the optimizer gives more than 6,000 warnings. That is mostly a combination of you not having enough data, modeling an outcome that is extremely poorly approximated by a Poisson distribution, and/or  otherwise doesn't model the random effects well (you only have 2 observations per `ID`).

However, if the data you provided is not representative of the actual data you are working with and instead the model converges with no warnings or errors, you can get p-values by passing the model object to `summary`: `summary(model1)`.